# Grafana 5 plugin development, how to save user data / panel state?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, grafana

I´m developing a Plugin for Grafana and I don't know how to save the panel status or how to save the data, entered by the user (I programmed a Graph and the user can provide a description and I don't know how to save this description). Maybe some of you guys know which grafana event I should use.

I cant be more specific on this point because I don't really know how to explain myself, hope this is enough input for you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You place your panel settings as properties in the panel property of the panel controller.

Everything on this.panel (from your PanelCtrl) is persisted when the user saves the dashboard.